# How do I enable VirtualMFADevice in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, multi-factor-authentication

I have a CloudFormation script that creates new users (with roles, policies etc).

I am hoping to ensure the new users have MFA enabled. The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-virtualmfadevice.html) mention you have to "attach the MFA device to an IAM user after creating the MFA" (even though there is a `Users` property as below?) but they only point to how to do this in the console and CLI.

```
  Type: AWS::IAM::VirtualMFADevice
    Properties:
      Users:
          - !Ref user1
          - !Ref user2
      VirtualMfaDeviceName: Something
```

Is this operation not supported in CloudFormation maybe?

Answer (score 0):

An MFA device is something that a user manages for himself/herself. In order to ensure that the users have MFA enabled, you can use an [IAM Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage.html). This example policy from Amazon explicitly denies all permissions for users (even, if there are other policies allowing them), unless they have MFA enabled. The only thing permitting is managing their own MFA device, so that they can add a device for themselves. These are the [details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_users-self-manage-mfa-and-creds.html) for users managing their MFA devices.

Comment: That's definitely one way to achieve it, thanks @kgiannakakis Keen to understand the CloudFormation angle properly though and how (or if even!?) that is meant to be used...

Comment: You are right that the documentation for AWS::IAM::VirtualMFADevice is at least incomplete. I don't know, how you could use it, as there doesn't seem to be a way to set the seed information. However, for anything that has to do with secrets creation, you can't do it only with Cloud Formation. Cloud Formation can't store secure information, so you need to combine it with something else.

Comment: Yeah I've integrated CloudFormation with SecretsManager, no problem :+1
It was really a fully-automated approach that I was after and struggling to understand what I've missed. But perhaps you're correct and the docs are somewhat incomplete? I might have to reach out to AWS Support and get one of their engineers to recommend the best approach for automated provisioning. Thanks a lot for your comments.